# find out what port an ipaddress is connected on

Tags: linux, rhel, security

Basically i have a connection on my linux server that is not known to me, it seems my server is being used in a ddos and i suspect this connection may have something to do with it.

I want to know what port this ip address is using to connect and also would be good to know what user they are using if that is possible?

Thanks

EDIT: The command `netstat -ntu` shows me the ports being used. I would still like to find out what user the `ip` is using.

Comment: Please, could you share more information with us? This subject is delicate and the question sounds a bit broad to me to be answered properly.

Comment: `netstat -tulpn` can be used to see open  connections and the processes that are using them.

Comment: So i used a netstat command to view all connections to my server. All where internal as i would expect apart from one which i dont recognise. My firewall is showing possible SYN flooding that is coming from my server which is why i suspect this ip.

I would like to know all i can really about this connection so knowing the port they are using to connect, user they are connected with etc. -tulpn doesnt show this suspect ip.

Comment: You can use `lsof` to show which processes use which connections. If you know the process, you should be able to figure out the user etc.

Comment: Thanks dirkt.
Can anyone tell me how to remove this connection from my server?

Comment: Try killing the process that's using the connection? `sudo kill -9 [PID]`

Comment: if you suspect your machine is hacked. Detach immediately from network, and do check how they hacked your server, what they hacked, and solve the problems.